# Voltage inside a Cylindrical Capacitor - Dealing With Signs

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, capacitance

In my intro E&M class, we were given an example problem to determine the voltage within a cylindrical capacitor as a function of radius. A diagram of such a cylindrical capacitor is below.

[image]

The solution from my instructor is as follows.

> Let the outer surface be denoted by "a" and the inner surface be denoted by "b". So, we have
>   $$\begin{align}\Delta V & = V_b - V_a\\ &= -\int_{r_a}^{r_b} \vec{E}\cdot\text{d}\vec{s}\\ &= -\int_{r_a}^{r_b}E\cos\theta\text{ d}s\end{align}$$
>   Now we note that $\cos\theta = -1$ in this case and then make the substitution $\text{d}s = - \text{d}r$.
>   $$\begin{align}\Delta V &= -\int_{r_a}^{r_b}E\cos\theta\text{ d}s\\&= \int_{r_a}^{r_b}E\text{ d}s\\&= -\int_{r_a}^{r_b}E\text{ d}r\end{align}$$

---

When we actually substitute in the expression for the electric field as a function of $r$, we get the correct answer. However, my concern with this solution is in the nature of the order of substitution.

When I approached this problem, instead of first making a substitution for $\cos\theta$, I first made the substitution $\text{d}\vec{s} = -\text{d}\vec{r}$. To me, this vector substitution made more sense than the scalar substitution of differentials since this would be more indicative of the opposite direction between the "direction of integration" and the radial vector.

So, using this approach, we get 
$$\begin{align}\Delta V & = V_b - V_a\\ &= -\int_{r_a}^{r_b} \vec{E}\cdot\text{d}\vec{s}\\ &= \int_{r_a}^{r_b}\vec{E}\cdot\text{d}\vec{r}\\&= \int_{r_a}^{r_b}E\cos\theta\text{ d}r\end{align}$$
Now, since the differential radial vector and the electric field are parallel, $\cos\theta = 1$, so we get 
$$\begin{align}\Delta V &= \int_{r_a}^{r_b}E\cos\theta\text{ d}r\\&=\int_{r_a}^{r_b}E\text{ d}r\end{align}$$
This is the negative of my instructor's solution, which obviously leads to the wrong solution. Where do I go wrong? Why can I not simply reverse the order in which my teacher makes substitutions?

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence in your instructor's solution

> Let the outer surface be denoted by "a" and the inner surface be denoted by "b".

is at variance with the diagram.

Your justification

> since this would be more indicative of the opposite direction between the "direction of integration" and the radial vector

for making the substitution $\text{d}\vec{s} = -\text{d}\vec{r}$ is incorrect.

[image]

The change in potential in moving from position $X$ to position $Y$ is $-\vec E \cdot d\vec s$.

Now make the substitution $d\vec s = dr \,\hat r$ where $dr$ is the **component** of the vector $d\vec s $ in the $\hat r$ direction, ie $dr$ could either be positive otr negative depending on the actual direction when taking the step.

So the change in potential is $-\vec E \cdot d\vec s = - E\,\hat r \cdot dr \,\hat r = - E\,dr$.

So what determines the sign of $dr$?
Well you do or rather the limits that you assign to the integration.

Suppose the limits are from lower limit $r_{\rm a}$ to upper limit $r_{\rm b}$ ie from left to right in the diagram.

When making that small incremental step $d\vec s$ the direction is from left to right and $-E\,dr \approx - E(r_{\rm Y}-r_{\rm X})$ which is a negative quantity ie the potential is decreasing and you will find that after doing the complete integration that $V_{\rm b} < $V_{\rm a}$.

Now what about having the limits of integration from lower limit $r_{\rm b}$ to upper limit $r_{\rm a}$ ie from right to left in the diagram.

When making that small incremental step $d\vec s$ the direction is from right to left and $-E\,dr \approx - E(r_{\rm X}-r_{\rm Y})$ which is a positive quantity ie the potential is  increasing and and again you will find that after doing the complete integration that $V_{\rm b} < $V_{\rm a}$.

---

In an example like this where you are moving parallel to the electric field lines all you need to do is the evaluate $\displaystyle -\int_{r_{\rm a}}^{r_{\rm b}} \vec E \cdot d\vec s= -\int_{r_{\rm a}}^{r_{\rm b}} E\,\hat r \cdot dr\,\hat r=-\int_{r_{\rm a}}^{r_{\rm b}} E\,dr$ and the sign of $dr$ will be taken care of by the limits integration as they indicate the direction of travel.